# Generate entities form existing database in Zend framework 2

Tags: php, entity-framework, orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I already have a database with two tables "Album" and "Email".
I tried to generate orm and entities from that using commands.

First I used the following command to generate orm

```
/opt/lampp/bin/php ./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping --from-database php ./module/Album/src/Album/Entity
```

That creates orm files as follows..

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo;

 $metadata->setInheritanceType(ClassMetadataInfo::INHERITANCE_TYPE_NONE);
 $metadata->setPrimaryTable(array(
    'name' => 'Album',
   ));
 $metadata-   
>setChangeTrackingPolicy(ClassMetadataInfo::CHANGETRACKING_DEFERRED_IMPLICIT);
 $metadata->mapField(array(
    'fieldName' => 'id',
    'columnName' => 'id',
    'type' => 'integer',
    'nullable' => false,
    'unsigned' => false,
   'comment' => '',
   'id' => true,
  ));
$metadata->mapField(array(
   'fieldName' => 'artist',
   'columnName' => 'artist',
   'type' => 'string',
   'nullable' => false,
   'length' => 255,
   'fixed' => false,
   'comment' => '',
  ));
$metadata->mapField(array(
   'fieldName' => 'title',
   'columnName' => 'title',
   'type' => 'string',
   'nullable' => false,
   'length' => 255,
   'fixed' => false,
   'comment' => '',
  ));
$metadata->setIdGeneratorType(ClassMetadataInfo::GENERATOR_TYPE_IDENTITY);
```

After that I run the below command to generate entities from that orm files

```
/opt/lampp/bin/php ./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:generate-entities /modules/Album/src/Album/Entity
```

But, the last command returns the error in command prompt like..

```
Notice: Undefined variable: metadata in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ZendSkeleton/module/Album/src/Album/Entity/Album.php on line 5

Fatal error: Call to a member function setInheritanceType() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ZendSkeleton/module/Album/src/Album/Entity/Album.php on line 5
```

The $metadata variable is undefined...

**Is there any thing wrong in what I did...?**

**How should I proceed next...?
Please help me....**

Comment: How did you initiate the variable $metadata ?

Comment: is $metadata supposed to be an object of ClassMetadataInfo?

Comment: The orm is generated automatically when the run the command.I initialize the variable $metadata as an object of ClassMetadataInfo. But that didn't work.

Comment: did you add the new keyword while initializing? example: $metadata = new ClassMetadataInfo();

Comment: Yes. I did like you mentioned above. But then it displayed an error about constructor. So I passed the entity name inside that. That also didn't work.

Comment: Is there any common way( a structured way) to generate entities including getters and setters in zend 2?